# Demasiado tiempo para la ejecucion

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo un query en sql server 2017 con el cual saco una factura referente, pero al momento de ejecutar el query demora mas de la hora para traer la informacion, y solo es 1 fila

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT  YEAR(E0.FECHA) as Anio, MONTH(E0.FECHA) as Mes,DAY(E0.FECHA) as Dia,CASE WHEN replace(E1.hydra,'','') IS NULL OR replace(E1.hydra,'','')='' THEN 'Manual' ELSE replace(E1.hydra,'','') END AS HydraM,
        E0.consecutivo,E0.fecha,E0.codtipodcto,E0.codigo'Nit',E0.codbodega,E3.nombre'NomBode',E1.codigo'CodArt',E2.nombre,SUM(E1.cantidad) AS Cantidad
FROM tblencfacturas E0 INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas E1 ON E0.consecutivo=E1.consecutivo
                            INNER JOIN tblarticulos E2 ON E2.codigo=E1.codigo
                            INNER JOIN tblbodegas E3 ON E3.codbodega=E1.codbodega
GROUP BY YEAR(E0.FECHA), MONTH(E0.FECHA),DAY(E0.FECHA),CASE WHEN replace(E1.hydra,'','') IS NULL OR replace(E1.hydra,'','')='' THEN 'Manual' ELSE replace(E1.hydra,'','') END,
        E0.consecutivo,E0.fecha,E0.codtipodcto,E0.codigo,E0.codbodega,E3.nombre,E1.codigo,E2.nombre
) AS F0  LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT YEAR(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Anio, MONTH(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Mes,DAY(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Dia,T0.D_FECHA as T_Fecha,T0.HOUR as T_hora,T0.NUME,T1.CODIGO as T_Codigo,T1.NOMBRE as T_nombre,SUM(T0.WEIGHT) AS T_Cantidad
FROM tbltickets T0 INNER JOIN tblarticulos T1 ON T0.CODE=T1.CODALTERNO
GROUP BY YEAR(T0.D_FECHA), MONTH(T0.D_FECHA),DAY(T0.D_FECHA),T0.D_FECHA,T0.HOUR,T0.NUME,T1.CODIGO,T1.NOMBRE
) AS T0 ON F0.Anio=T0.T_Anio AND F0.Mes=T0.T_Mes AND F0.Dia=T0.T_Dia AND F0.HydraM=T0.NUME AND F0.CodArt=T0.T_CODIGO
WHERE F0.Anio='2019' AND F0.Mes='01' AND F0.Dia='16' AND F0.HydraM IN ('00083')
```

Comment: No es recomendable usar `subquerys` y en lo posible evitar los `join`, éste tipo de consultas cuestan a la base de datos. Ya con el fin de tener mayor rapidez recomiendo indexar.

Comment: *GROUP BY* hace que las consultas se hagan muy lentas, en mi experiencia yo capturo todas las filas repetidas y utilizo al leguaje de programación (ejemplo PHP) para mostrar solo un resultado. Sinceramente no sé si sea una buena práctica, pero me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo haría esto primero para mejorar el tiempo de respuesta...

Creo que otro where parecido en  la segunda parte de tu query (el segundo subquery) hará mas rápida tu consulta también.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  
         YEAR(E0.FECHA) as Anio
        ,MONTH(E0.FECHA) as Mes
        ,DAY(E0.FECHA) as Dia
        ,CASE 
            WHEN replace(E1.hydra,'','') IS NULL OR replace(E1.hydra,'','')='' 
            THEN 'Manual' 
            ELSE replace(E1.hydra,'','') 
        END AS HydraM
        ,E0.consecutivo
        ,E0.fecha
        ,E0.codtipodcto
        ,E0.codigo'Nit'
        ,E0.codbodega
        ,E3.nombre'NomBode'
        ,E1.codigo'CodArt'
        ,E2.nombre
        ,SUM(E1.cantidad) AS Cantidad
    FROM tblencfacturas E0 
        INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas  E1 ON E0.consecutivo    = E1.consecutivo                            
        INNER JOIN tblarticulos     E2 ON E2.codigo         = E1.codigo
        INNER JOIN tblbodegas       E3 ON E3.codbodega      = E1.codbodega
    --Esto cambiaria de tu codigo
    WHERE YEAR(E0.FECHA)='2019' AND MONTH(E0.FECHA) ='01' AND DAY(E0.FECHA)='16' 
        AND (CASE 
            WHEN replace(E1.hydra,'','') IS NULL OR replace(E1.hydra,'','')='' 
            THEN 'Manual' 
            ELSE replace(E1.hydra,'','') 
            END) = ('00083')--Puedes poner el IN ('00083'), si vas a consultar mas codigos, si no dejale el igual
    GROUP BY 
         YEAR(E0.FECHA)
        ,MONTH(E0.FECHA)
        ,DAY(E0.FECHA)
        ,CASE WHEN replace(E1.hydra,'','') IS NULL OR replace(E1.hydra,'','')='' THEN 'Manual' ELSE replace(E1.hydra,'','') END
        ,E0.consecutivo
        ,E0.fecha
        ,E0.codtipodcto
        ,E0.codigo
        ,E0.codbodega
        ,E3.nombre
        ,E1.codigo
        ,E2.nombre
) AS F0  
    LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        YEAR(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Anio
        ,MONTH(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Mes
        ,DAY(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Dia
        ,T0.D_FECHA as T_Fecha
        ,T0.HOUR as T_hora
        ,T0.NUME
        ,T1.CODIGO as T_Codigo
        ,T1.NOMBRE as T_nombre
        ,SUM(T0.WEIGHT) AS T_Cantidad
    FROM tbltickets T0 
        INNER JOIN tblarticulos T1 ON T0.CODE=T1.CODALTERNO
    --Mi sugerencia es que tambien pongas un where aqui y delimites este query
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR(T0.D_FECHA)
        , MONTH(T0.D_FECHA)
        ,DAY(T0.D_FECHA)
        ,T0.D_FECHA,T0.HOUR
        ,T0.NUME,T1.CODIGO
        ,T1.NOMBRE
) AS T0 
    ON F0.Anio=T0.T_Anio AND F0.Mes=T0.T_Mes AND F0.Dia=T0.T_Dia AND F0.HydraM=T0.NUME AND F0.CodArt=T0.T_CODIGO
-- Este where ya no es necesario aqui
--WHERE F0.Anio='2019' AND F0.Mes='01' AND F0.Dia='16' AND F0.HydraM IN ('00083')
```

Creo que gran parte de la falla del query es que COMPARA TODO CONTRA TODO de toda la historia de facturas y de ventas, si delimitas usando el where tendrá que por ende ser mas rápida la consulta.

Saludos, espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, mejoro notablemente el rendimiento, paso de mas de 1 hora a menos de 5 segundos

Comment: Ese era el problema, no delimitabas el subquery y traías siempre TODA la tabla.  Me da gusto haberte ayudado.  Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Veo que las respuestas anteriores pueden mejorar el rendimiento de consulta, sin embargo considera revisar que los campos con los que haces los JOIN y los WHERE en la base se encuentren indexados, cuando éstos campos no se encuentran indexados puedes encontrar bajo rendimiento en el desempeño de las consultas, o por el contrario existe el indice, pero se encuentra muy fragmentado, debes realizar 2 cosas.
 1. Verifica si es conveniente indexar el campo, depende de la administración que tengas en el servidor.
 2. Reconstruye ó reindexa el indice, te dejo 1 ejemplo de como reindexar:
 2.1. DBCC DBREINDEX (tabla, '', 75)

Answer (score 0):

No se cuentos registros tienes de cada fecha pero si son demasiados considera
hacer join de las tablas E2 y E3 hasta el final antes del ultimo WHERE.

Mientras menos campos sean mas rápido procesa el motor, primero debes obtener las facturas mediante las fechas y trabajar con las Llaves luego, cuando ya tengas la información que quieres, hacer las relaciones a los artículos y bodegas.

```
DECLARE @ANIO   INT = '2019'
,       @MES    INT = '1'
,       @Dia    INT = '16'

SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT  YEAR(E0.FECHA) as Anio
            ,   MONTH(E0.FECHA) as Mes
            ,   DAY(E0.FECHA) as Dia
            ,   CASE WHEN replace(E1.hydra,'','') IS NULL OR replace(E1.hydra,'','')='' THEN 'Manual' ELSE replace(E1.hydra,'','') END AS HydraM
            ,   E0.consecutivo
            ,   E0.fecha
            ,   E0.codtipodcto
            ,   E0.codigo'Nit'
            ,   E0.codbodega
            ,   E3.nombre'NomBode'
            ,   E1.codigo'CodArt'
            ,   E2.nombre
            ,   SUM(E1.cantidad) AS Cantidad

        FROM        tblencfacturas  E0 
        INNER JOIN  tblmvtofacturas E1 ON E0.consecutivo=E1.consecutivo
        INNER JOIN  tblarticulos    E2 ON E2.codigo=E1.codigo
        INNER JOIN  tblbodegas      E3 ON E3.codbodega=E1.codbodega
        WHERE YEAR(E0.FECHA)    = @ANIO
        AND   MONTH(E0.FECHA)   = @MES
        AND   DAY(E0.FECHA)     = @Dia
        GROUP BY 
                YEAR(E0.FECHA)
            ,   MONTH(E0.FECHA)
            ,   DAY(E0.FECHA)
            ,   CASE WHEN replace(E1.hydra,'','') IS NULL OR replace(E1.hydra,'','')='' THEN 'Manual' ELSE replace(E1.hydra,'','') END
            ,   E0.consecutivo
            ,   E0.fecha
            ,   E0.codtipodcto
            ,   E0.codigo
            ,   E0.codbodega
            ,   E3.nombre
            ,   E1.codigo
            ,   E2.nombre
) AS F0  
LEFT JOIN-- TRATA DE EVITAR LOS LEFT, SOLO SON PARA TABLA CON POCOS REGISTROS, COMO CATALOGOS NO PARA SUBCONSULTAS
(   SELECT  YEAR(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Anio
    ,       MONTH(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Mes
    ,       DAY(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Dia
    ,       T0.D_FECHA as T_Fecha
    ,       T0.HOUR as T_hora
    ,       T0.NUME
    ,       T1.CODIGO as T_Codigo
    ,       T1.NOMBRE as T_nombre
    ,       SUM(T0.WEIGHT) AS T_Cantidad
    FROM        tbltickets T0 
    INNER JOIN  tblarticulos T1 ON T0.CODE=T1.CODALTERNO
    WHERE   YEAR(T0.D_FECHA)    = @ANIO
    AND     MONTH(T0.D_FECHA)   = @MES
    AND     DAY(T0.D_FECHA)     = @Dia
    GROUP BY 
            YEAR(T0.D_FECHA)
        ,   MONTH(T0.D_FECHA)
        ,   DAY(T0.D_FECHA)
        ,   T0.D_FECHA
        ,   T0.HOUR
        ,   T0.NUME
        ,   T1.CODIGO
        ,   T1.NOMBRE
) AS T0 ON F0.Anio=T0.T_Anio AND F0.Mes=T0.T_Mes AND F0.Dia=T0.T_Dia AND F0.HydraM=T0.NUME AND F0.CodArt=T0.T_CODIGO
WHERE F0.HydraM IN ('00083')
```

Un saludo

Comment: Porque cambiaste la respuesta por esta? lo que dice de los campos no es cierto, eso no le cuesta casi nada al SQL lo que le cuesta es comparar gran volumen de registros y si comparas contra strings o varchars también allí es donde le cuesta mucho tiempo, en tu caso el numero de campos que consulta no tenia nada que ver con la lentitud, era el volumen de rows que comparabas.

Answer (score 0):

Sin tener una idea clara de cómo están estructurados los datos que quieres obtener, pero basándome en lo que se ve, yo haría la query del siguiente modo:

---

```
with F0 as (
    SELECT  
    YEAR(E0.FECHA) as Anio, MONTH(E0.FECHA) as Mes,DAY(E0.FECHA) as Dia,
    CASE 
    WHEN replace(E1.hydra,'','') IS NULL OR replace(E1.hydra,'','')='' THEN 'Manual' 
    ELSE replace(E1.hydra,'','') END AS HydraM,
    E0.consecutivo,E0.fecha,E0.codtipodcto,E0.codigo'Nit',E0.codbodega,
    E3.nombre'NomBode',E1.codigo'CodArt',E2.nombre,SUM(E1.cantidad) AS Cantidad
    FROM tblencfacturas E0 
    INNER JOIN tblmvtofacturas E1 ON E0.consecutivo=E1.consecutivo AND YEAR(E0.FECHA)='2019' AND MONTH(E0.FECHA)='01' AND DAY(E0.FECHA)='16'
    INNER JOIN tblarticulos E2 ON E2.codigo=E1.codigo 
    INNER JOIN tblbodegas E3 ON E3.codbodega=E1.codbodega
    GROUP BY YEAR(E0.FECHA), MONTH(E0.FECHA),DAY(E0.FECHA),CASE WHEN replace(E1.hydra,'','') IS NULL OR replace(E1.hydra,'','')='' THEN 'Manual' ELSE replace(E1.hydra,'','') END,
    E0.consecutivo,E0.fecha,E0.codtipodcto,E0.codigo,E0.codbodega,E3.nombre,E1.codigo,E2.nombre
),
T0 as (
    SELECT YEAR(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Anio, MONTH(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Mes,DAY(T0.D_FECHA) as T_Dia,
    T0.D_FECHA as T_Fecha,T0.HOUR as T_hora,T0.NUME,T1.CODIGO as T_Codigo,
    T1.NOMBRE as T_nombre,SUM(T0.WEIGHT) AS T_Cantidad
    FROM tbltickets T0 
    INNER JOIN tblarticulos T1 ON T0.CODE=T1.CODALTERNO
    GROUP BY YEAR(T0.D_FECHA), MONTH(T0.D_FECHA),DAY(T0.D_FECHA),T0.D_FECHA,T0.HOUR,T0.NUME,T1.CODIGO,T1.NOMBRE
)
SELECT *
FROM F0 f0
LEFT JOIN T0 t0 ON ON F0.Anio=T0.T_Anio AND F0.Mes=T0.T_Mes AND F0.Dia=T0.T_Dia AND F0.HydraM=T0.NUME AND F0.CodArt=T0.T_CODIGO AND F0.HydraM IN ('00083')
with ur
```

---

- Dividiría la query en 2 tablas temporales (F0,T0).
- En el primer Inner join de F0 incluyo las condiciones que estaban en tu Where al final. Siempre es más eficiente filtrar en un JOIN que en un WHERE, si tienes opción.
  La diferencia es que con las condiciones en el JOIN estás haciendo la unión sobre los datos que cumplen esas condiciones, mientras que del otro modo, lo haces sobre todos y después filtras los que las cumplen.
- Haría el Left join al final, uniendo las dos tablas temporales. Al igual que antes, podría las condiciones de filtrado en el JOIN, si es posible, para evitar arrastrar datos de más.

  - El with ur del final, no siempre es necesario, pero si vas lanzar una query muy pesada, evita que la query sature el servidor de BD.